# qml c++ property bindings with multiple threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qml

I am creating an modular application. It has a `Core`, and a few modules, amongs which is a gui module. These modules can be started via the command line:

```
myApp gui=qml=qmlFile.qml connection=serial=/dev/ttyS1
```

will start the app with one (multiple is also possible) gui and one serial connection. There is always one `Router` object, which handles the connection. Guis are loaded by a class that looks like this:

```
class Gui :QObject{
  Core* core;
  public:
  QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
  public slots:
  void start(){
    engine.load("qrc:/gui/from/command/line.qml");
  }
```

In the gui i have a nice bit of qml called `ConnectionController{}` which is an easy way of adding/removing connections. But this is only the first of it's kind: in the end every module should have a qml component for controlling it.

This all works fine, but now i am trying to add multiple threads. I want to have a `RouterThread` and a `GuiThread`. This in itself was simply a matter of changing the creation of the `Router` (by the `Core`) to this:

```
m_router = new Router(this /*not as parent, just as pointer*/);
m_router->moveToThread(&routerThread);
```

(gui's still live in the main thread for now)
After this everything still works fine, except for qml property bindings.

```
QQmlEngine: Illegal attempt to connect to SerialConnection(0x7f58d00013a0) that is in a different thread than the QML engine
```

Because `Gui` and it's child `QQmlEngine engine` live in the `guiThread` while the `SerialConnection` lives in the `routerThread`.
Signals and slots between `Router` and `Gui` (without qml) do work, because they are handled by default as asynchronous by qt. (as long as the appropriate types are defined.)

Comment: What is your question? The reason why binding to a property of an object with different thread affinity from the QQmlEngine won't work?

Comment: Mosty, "how do i fix this error?" but also, "why isn't it possible like this?" Anything usefull basically ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, no, you cant access threaded objects from your gui and should not try to either.

You need to build a c++ model that lives in the main thread that is exposed to qml. Inside this model you can connect to signals emitted by your threads via a queuedconnection and link them to the models' own signals.
Also you should make sure that when you read data from an object owned by another thread, everything is properly mutexed or you will be reading garbage.

Comment: What do you mean by multiplexed?

Comment: With multiplexed I meant mutexed. Brainfart ;-).
If you don't know what that is you should look up the docs for QMutex or std::mutex

Comment: Haha, makes sense now :)  I will now make a `Router` and a `RouterWorker` and a `Connection` and a `ConnectionRef`... It's a bit of a shame that i have to do it like this, because i'd have to do this for every module i will add :(