# Direct interaction between Qt/QML frontend and C++ backend/model in another thread

Tags: multithreading, qt, qml, backend

I have a Qt/QML (QT 5.7.1) application that needs to interact with a (quite complex) C++ backend, that lives in another thread.

Currently, I followed the suggestion from the blog article https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/ and created a C++ class "MainController", that is registered via

```
qmlRegisterType<MainController>("MainController", 1, 0, "MainController");
```

and instantiated from the main QML file like this:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    MainController {
        id: mainController
    }

    ...
}
```

In its constructor, the MainController (which runs in the same thread as the QML code) creates a Worker object, which is then moved into its own thread:

```
MainController::MainController() : QObject()
{
    state = GUI_State::HW_STANDBY;

    QThread* thread = new QThread;
    Worker* worker = new Worker();
    worker->moveToThread(thread);
    connect(worker, SIGNAL (error(QString)), this, SLOT (errorString(QString)));
    connect(thread, SIGNAL (started()), worker, SLOT (process()));
    connect(worker, SIGNAL (finished()), thread, SLOT (quit()));
    connect(worker, SIGNAL (finished()), worker, SLOT (deleteLater()));
    connect(thread, SIGNAL (finished()), thread, SLOT (deleteLater()));
    ...
    thread->start();
    qDebug() << "Thread started";
}
```

Now, I can communicate using signals this way:

```
QML -> MainController -> Worker
QML <- MainController <- Worker
```

But there is a lot of overhead for this: to make a "property" of the Worker available to the GUI, I have to send a signal to the MainController, which needs a slot to receive the signal, which then triggers another signal, which then can be received from within the QML code.  Same applies to the other direction.

How can I establish a direct link between the backend (Worker class) and the QML layer, preserving the two-thread architecture ?

Comment: Expose worker thread(pointer to object) as property. QThread inherits QObject.

Comment: You can directly connect a signal to another signal.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont use `Q_PROPERTY`, you can instance the worker itself in QML You can also make your worker-instance a context-property by

```
Worker* workerObj = new Worker();   
engine->rootContext()->setContextProperty("qmlWorker", workerObj );
```

This will only work for Signal/Slot-Connection, aswell as `Q_INVOKABLE`.

If you want to use QML-Properties via a different Threads, I would suggest to use your approach as it is a save way to handle Threads in Qt in general.

Comment: This is fine, as long as you **only** use signals and slots in qml, and **no** properties. Keep you thread approach, and add the second code line to your setup code. You can the access the worker from qml using `qmlWorker`

Comment: How do I need to reference qmlWorker in qml to get this working?  I tried the setContextProperty above, but when I use e.g. "text: qmlWorker.number2" in qml I get the runtime error "QQmlEngine: Illegal attempt to connect to Worker(0x55f1d9f19630) that is in a different thread than the QML engine QQmlApplicationEngine(0x55f1da08b6c0."

Comment: Edited the original answer.

Answer (score -1):

According to [qml c++ property bindings with multiple threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33490185/qml-c-property-bindings-with-multiple-threads?rq=1), one can't access properties that live in another thread.

Comment: This is not an answer but a comment. It shouldn't be posted as an answer.

Comment: @talamaki: what exactly do you mean?  My original question was, how to directly link QML to the worker thread.  In the linked discussion it turned out, that properties can't be accessed if the are in another thread.  For me, this answers my question.  So I posted it here for others to comment on it.