# Illegal attempt to connect to variable that is in a different thread than the QML engine

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I've created an object (which inherits from `QObject`) in my main.cpp and I'm passing this object to another thread. To simply things, my main looks like below

main.cpp

```
QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
ClientListWrapper clients;   // Inherits from QObject
 if (!clients.initialize())
        return -1;
args2thread->Pointer2clients = &clients;     // Passing this object to thread 
std::thread Listening_thread(thread_function, args2thread);  // Creating a thread
```

Now in my thread function I'm modifying clients object i.e.

myThread.cpp

```
//Receive data from client here
.
args2thread->clients->addClient(data);  // Store the received data
.
```

QT responds with the following runtime errors:

**QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
QQmlEngine: Illegal attempt to connect to Client(0x11198860) that is in a different thread than the QML engine QQmlApplicationEngine**

Comment: You'll have too pass a message back to the main thread and run your UI-manipulation code there.

Comment: why you didn't use [QThread](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html) class? `The QThread class provides a platform-independent way to manage threads` and also it inherits `QObject` which means that using this makes your work so easy.

Comment: So I must have to use QThreads in this case ? And the manipulation i do in the listeing-thread should be communicated back to main loop via signal/slots ?

Answer (score 0):

```
ClientListWrapper clients;   // Inherits from QObject
```

clients object is owned by main GUI thread as it is created in main.cpp.

```
args2thread->Pointer2clients = &clients;     // Passing this object to thread
```

Here you are only passing the address of the clients object, the clients object is still owned by main GUI thread.

```
args2thread->clients->addClient(data);  // Store the received data
```

Here you are trying to add children to clients object from a different thread. Thus the error, QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.

```
QQmlEngine: Illegal attempt to connect to Client(0x11198860) that is in a different thread than the QML engine QQmlApplicationEngine
```

This error occurs when you try to bind your GUI to non GUI thread objects.

What you need to do is keep all modifications of the clients object in the main GUI thread. These modifications can be triggered by different thread via signal-slot mechanism.
Also make sure that access to different thread objects is properly mutexed.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33505504/16586783 & https://stackoverflow.com/q/47790210/16586783